# 404 Page Not Found The page you requested was not found - CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new on using CodeIngiter framwork. I tested my code on localhost. It works perfectly.

But when I put the files on remote server. It gives me:

"404 Page Not Found - The page you requested was not found."

when I call the controller through url: http://www.mysite.com/dev/application/facebook/show_info

However the welcome page shows correctly. I can modify the welcome.php controller to check the 
base url. Then, I test the url so I try to follow the letter case (since my controller class is called: Show_Info.php) http://www.mysite.com/dev/application/facebook/Show_Info

It shows another error message:
"An Error Was Encountered - Unable to locate the model you have specified: fb_user_model"

I search via google, stack overflow, .... etc but I still cannot find the solution.
Please help and sorry for my bad English.

file tree:

```
(http://www.mysite.com)
│
└──application 
    │
    ├───dev
    │   ├───codeigniter
    │   │    |───system
    │   │    └───application
    │   │         |─controller
    │   │         |  ├welcome.php
    │   │         |  └facebook
    │   │         |     └Show_Info.php
    │   │ 
    │   ├───index.php
    │   ├───.htaccess
    │   |
```

.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

base_url:

> http://www.mysite.com/dev/application/

Comment: What do your `config/routes.php` and `config/config.php` look like?

Answer (score 2):

First of all you should remove codeigniter folder from you structure. Put you application, system folders directly in you DIV folder. 
And also in htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /dev/
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

And change base_url `http://www.mysite.com/dev/`
I hope this will help you

Answer (score 1):

change your base_url to http://www.yoursite.com don't put the application folder name in base url the index.php file will read it because it is set from the index.php.
i hope this will solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

If you have developed on windows on localhost and the server is linux you have to put the controllers and models php files to start with an uppercase.
For example:
**ctl_base.php** -> **Ctl_base.php**

Answer (score 0):

Try to make all conterollers and models files first letter uppercase. Ex: myController.php -> MyController.php